# Silabs bootloader for new devices

Tags: microcontroller, bootloader

Can anybody help in my question? I have got EFM8BB3 MCU (new one from EFM8) and I suppose that it has an internal hardware bootloader, according datasheet on it on UART0 interface.

But [AN945: EFM8 Factory Bootloader User's Guide](https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/application-notes/an945-efm8-factory-bootloader-user-guide.pdf)
does not verify this, and because of that I do not understand how to use UART0.

Can I use it for both programming and application?

Please help, and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

> All devices come pre-programmed with a UART0 bootloader. This bootloader resides in the code security page, which is the last page
> of code flash; **it can be erased if it is not needed.**

> When a bootloader is present, the device will jump to the bootloader vector after any reset, allowing the bootloader to run. The bootloader then determines if the device should stay in bootload mode or jump to the reset vector located at 0x0000.

If you didn't erase it, then it's still there and can be used for loading blank chips or updating them.

[[source](https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/data-sheets/efm8bb3-datasheet.pdf)]

Comment: Thanks!!
Now I understand, but one question still exist
If I already use UART0 in my application program can I use bootloader for programming MCU via UART0 too?
Is it necessary to togle some configuration pin to switch?